# How to have a generic type argument be itself a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am working with an example where I have two generic arguments to a type in typescript, but I would like the second generic type to take the first generic type. Something along these lines

```js
type NestedMess<T, V> = (t: V<T>) => void
```

However, I get `Type 'V' is not generic. ts(2315)`. Is there a way I can indicate that `V` will be a type that itself is generic?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Because I don't think you *should* need that. If `V` is a generic, then you should just pass that there, e.g., `NestedMess<string, Array<string>>`

Comment: @VLAZ I'm using react where I have multiple props that are themselves generic and the first argument `T` is to the generic props argument and `V` is the props in this case. Your solution works, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without repeating `string`, as in your solution.

Comment: No, that is not supported.  [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) is the relevant issue.  There are some workarounds in there but none of them are particularly nice.  It would be neat to see an actual [mcve] though because maybe something less than full higher-kinded types will meet your needs.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your props? You can have `V` extending a certain Generic interface.